# How to add a radio button to each individual object in a mongoDB database, and update a certain field?

Tags: python, html, flask, pymongo

What i have tried is: 
 
My python -

```
@app.route('/approveStudent', methods=['POST'])
def approveStudent():
users = mongo.db.users
studentRadio = request.form['studentRadio']
result = users.update_one({'user_id': 469}, {'$set': {'approved' : 1}})

return redirect(url_for('profile'))
```

In my database there is a user_id who is 469 and that i want approved to be 1.

My HTML:
    I have a form which returns {{ students }}

How would i loop through all students not just one user_id and put them in a radio button to approve eg. Set approved to 1.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through your Python list object in JavaScript/JQuery on the client-side. Serve the list via HTTP to the client page and iterate through the array with JavaScript, inserting HTML elements for each object in the array.

Add a JavaScript event listener to each radio button on toggle that triggers an HTTP request to your flask app, triggering an update of the corresponding value in your Mongo. Use PyMongo to create a mongo client object, and then use that to query your database.

PyMongo documentation:

http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html

Iterating through JavaScript array:

```
for (y = 0; y <arrayRecievedFromXMLHTTPRequest.length; y++){

    javascriptArray = []; //make sure this is declared globally

    element = document.getElementById(<containerDivId>).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<div id="'+ "radioButton" + String(y) + '" class="myRadioButton" ></div>');

    javascriptArray.push(element);
}
```

Javascript/Flask HTTP boilerplate:

```
for (i = 0; i < javascriptArray.length; i++) {
    javaScriptArray[i].addEventListener('click',function(event){

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState ===4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                        jsonn = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        //use response from Flask/Mongo to update page here.

        }

    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", '/<route>/<arguments>', true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    },false);
}
```

Important to keep data persistence, logic and interface separate.

Hope that’s helpful.

Comment: @wp78de might do just that once I’m back to my laptop